# How to call function only after the executing of the other function is completly finished

Tags: javascript, aem

In the following code, I would like to reload the siteadmin pages with the function `siteAdmin.reloadPages()` *only after* the storing of the pages porperties `CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction(dialog.form, config);`is executed sucessfully.

the following function submits a form and then calls a `callback()` function, which in turn reloads the siteadmin pages:

```
function foo(dialog, config, callback) {
    var action = new CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction(dialog.form, config);
    dialog.form.doAction(action);
    dialog[dialog.closeAction]();

    callback();
}
```

function call:

```
foo(dialog,action, function() {
    var siteAdmin = CQ.Ext.getCmp(window.CQ_SiteAdmin_id);
    siteAdmin.reloadPages();
});
```

The problem is that the siteadmin pages are not reladed after the pageProperties (`dialog.form`) has been successfully submitted. For example the pageTitle loaded is the old value.

How to reload siteadmin pages only after the form has been successfully submitted?

Comment: Doesn't `doAction` take a callback itself when it is asynchronous?

Comment: Can you specify a callback in `config` or does `doAction` accept a callback argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to specify the success function in the config, something like the one shown below.

```
function foo(dialog, config, callback) {
    var action = new CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction(dialog.form, {
        success: function(){
            var siteAdmin = CQ.Ext.getCmp(window.CQ_SiteAdmin_id);
            siteAdmin.reloadPages();
        }
    });
    dialog.form.doAction(action);
    dialog[dialog.closeAction]();
}
```

This would ensure that the siteadmin is reloaded only after you request succeeds.

Check the further options available for your config [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction).

Answer (score 2):

You should call the callback of foo from success callback of CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction

```
function foo(dialog, config, callback) {
    var action = new CQ.form.SlingSubmitAction(dialog.form, 
       {
         params: config.params,
         success: function(frm, resp) {
           callback();
         }
       });
    dialog.form.doAction(action);
    dialog[dialog.closeAction]();
}
```

Comment: sounds to be a good idea. I tried the suggestion of rakhi4110 and it works :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any sort of test for whether or not the form-submission was successful.  You could simply avoid calling the callback() function until after such a test has been passed.  Or, you could put the test inside the callback() function, and not do the page-reload until after the test has been passed.  OR, you can estimate how long it takes for the form-submission to be transmitted to the Web Server, and how long it takes the Server to process the data, and then do something like this:

```
 setTimeOut("callback();", 500); //wait 500 milliseconds (sample estimate)
```

OR

```
 setTimeOut("siteAdmin.reloadPages();", 500); //inside the callback() function
```

Note this assumes the submitted data is always successfully processed, but using setTimeout() is most certainly a generic way to ensure one function is DONE, before another gets called.

Comment: delying the process with timeout is not a good idea in my case :(

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear about something --if you know that it takes 100 milliseconds for the Web Server to receive and process the submitted data, you can specify a 100-millisecond timeout, instead of the half-second timeout guesstimated in my suggested Answer.  You definitely have a built-in delay already, because of the nature of the network; I'm saying you can match your secondary function-call to be in alignment with that delay (not introduce significant extra delay).  The problem remains, though, that the proposed Answer assumes that the submitted data is always valid.